set default DNS in ubuntu
I am new with ubuntu
few days ago I changed my dns like this :
sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf

and after adding two new DNS I saved it
now I wanna to get it back to the default
but when I open the resolv.conf
I see this :
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.
#
# This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
# /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
~ 

and it seems nothing has changed
but I know that DNS has changed and I can see it's effects .
so , How can I get it back to default ?

This is, for Ubuntu, the default. The message in the file seems rather clear: the file is a stub and is managed by systemd-resolved. It also states that you should not edit it, probably because systemd-resolved will overwrite it at it own whims.

Are you sure that you managed to edit the file using sudo /etc/resolv.conf? I'd expect an error message - sudo: /etc/resolv.conf: command not found since resolv.conf is not an executable ...

it was typing mistake
i actually used
sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf

